# How access and edit global variable from two functions in separated files in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, global

This how my shortcode function is:
Here I use a global variable `$displayed_posts_ids` which I want to access and edit in another function; should I redeclare it in the other file?

```
function posts_mobile($atts)
{
    global $displayed_posts_ids;
    $html = "";
    if (rw_is_mobile())
    {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'exclude' => array(get_the_id()),
        );
        $posts_array = get_posts($args);
        // var_dump($posts_array);
        $ids = get_the_id() . ",";
        if (count($posts_array) > 0)
        {
            $html .= "<div class='battle-block'>";
            $html .= "<div id='posts' class='row items-posts'>";
            foreach ($posts_array as $post)
            {
                $html .= show_post_selected($post->ID);
                $ids .= $post->ID . ",";
            }
            $html .= "</div></div>";
        }
        $ids = rtrim($ids, ",");
        $displayed_posts_ids .= $ids;
        $html .="<script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    $(window).scroll(function(){
                        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()-$(window).height()){  
                            alert('" . $displayed_posts_ids . "');
                            check_page_end();
                        }

                    });
                });
                </script>";
        return $html;
    }
}
```

And here the function where I want to edit and access my global variable in :

```
function ajax_get_other_posts()
{
    $ids_posts = explode(',', $displayed_posts_ids);
    if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'ajax_get_other_posts'))
    {
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'exclude' => $ids_posts,
        );
        $posts_array = get_posts($args);
        if (!empty($posts_array))
        {
            $ids = "";
            foreach ($posts_array as $post)
            {
                $html .= show_post_selected($post->ID);
                $ids .= $post->ID . ",";
            }
            $displayed_posts_ids .= ',' . rtrim($ids, ",");
            $params_encoded = json_encode($html);
            echo $params_encoded;
        }

        exit;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `$displayed_posts_ids` in your `ajax_get_other_posts()` method than you have to again call `global` variable, like this:

```
function ajax_get_other_posts(){  
    global $displayed_posts_ids;
    $ids_posts = explode(',', $displayed_posts_ids);
    //..
    //..
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still cant access it cuz when i display it i got null function ajax_get_other_posts(){   
 global $displayed_posts_ids;
 var_dump($displayed_posts_ids);